# Celery + Eventlet + non blocking requests

Tags: python, celery, python-requests, eventlet, grequests

I am using Python `requests` in celery `workers` to make large number of (~10/sec) API calls(includes GET,POST, PUT, DELETE). Each request takes around 5-10s to complete.

I tried running celery workers in `eventlet` pool, with 1000 concurrency.

Since `requests` are blocking process each concurrent connection is waiting on one request.

How do I make `requests` asynchronous?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use eventlet [monkey patching](http://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html) to make any pure python library non-blocking.

- patch single library

  ```py
  # import requests  # instead do this:
  import eventlet
  requests = eventlet.import_patched('requests')
  ```

  packages [erequests](https://pypi.org/project/erequests/) and [grequests](https://pypi.org/project/grequests/) could be stripped down to these two lines.
- patch everything

  ```py
  import eventlet
  eventlet.monkey_patch()  # must execute as early as possible
  ...
  # everything is non-blocking now:
  import requests, amqp, memcache, paramiko, redis
  ```

**Update**: there is [known issue](https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/7) with monkey patching requests library. If you get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name utils
```

, then modify import line to

```py
requests = eventlet.import_patched('requests.__init__')
```

Comment: Perfect ! 
Only problem was I was unable to do 
`requests = eventlet.import_patched('requests')` 
it was giving cannot import utils (`from . import utils`) 
So I have changed it to `requests = eventlet.import_patched('requests.__init__')` as per 
https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues/7 

thanks again

Comment: @Maddy, apart from patching the request library , was anything else required to make requests async and also was there any change in the way the response was collected post request? Post patching can we still do resp   = requests.get("http://google.com")?

Comment: @amrx At the time It worked, but I am sure they must have updated the patching now.

Comment: @amrx apart from patching, everything works as expected.

Comment: @temoto, Do you need to patch? The documentation is not certain about it and even the gevent and eventlet official examples dont patch.https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/examples/gevent/tasks.py

Comment: @amrx You must either execute `eventlet.monkey_patch()` or use `eventlet.import_patched('module_name')` for every module with network code. Celery does the first option implicitly if you specify eventlet worker type. https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/b5b64945daaba87a7d975b1b4fca08b0948b91bb/celery/__init__.py#L99

Answer (score 3):

from the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests):

> there are lots of projects out there that combine Requests with one of
>   Python’s asynchronicity frameworks. Two excellent examples are
>   [grequests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests) and [requests-futures.](https://github.com/ross/requests-futures)

for eventlet specifically you can use [erequests](http://github.com/saghul/erequests).

Comment: Please Edit the answer to include this link so that I can accept it