# Multithreading within a Celery Worker

Tags: python, multithreading, rabbitmq, celery, api-design

I am using Celery with RabbitMQ to process data from API requests. The process goes as follows:

**Request** > **API** > **RabbitMQ** > **Celery Worker** > **Return**

Ideally I would spawn more celery workers but I am restricted by memory constraints.

Currently, the bottleneck in my process is fetching and downloading the data from the URLs passed into the worker. Roughy, the process looks like this:

```py
def celery_gets_job(url):
    data = fetches_url(url)       # takes 0.1s to 1.0s (bottleneck)
    result = processes_data(data) # takes 0.1s
    return result
```

This is unacceptable as the worker is locked up for a while while fetching the URL. I am looking at improving this through threading, but I am unsure what the best practices are.

- Is there a way to make the celery worker download the incoming data asynchronously while processing the data at the same time in a different thread?
- Should I have separate workers fetching and processing, with some form of message passing, possibly via RabbitMQ?

Comment: You can consider using something like [multiprocessing pipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe)  within celery task by creating two multiprocesses. Ofcourse your multiprocessing processes should be restriced by pool. Sharing fetched url's large data over rabbitmq/result backend would not be good idea if I am not wrong. Celery low level api's can also have some similar kind of functionality.

Comment: I am not aware of RabbitMQ but what I think is multiprocessing will be more suitable for you than multithreading as `celery_gets_job` has multiple non-atomic operations and this will create problems while using multithreading. You can use Queue where data is populated by pool of processes running `fetches_url(url)` and another process(es) to carry out `processes_data(data)`

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315657/celery-eventlet-non-blocking-requests

Comment: This post https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11889549 by the creator of Celery may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`eventlet`](http://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html) library, you can patch the standard libraries for making them asynchronous.

First import the async urllib2:

```
from eventlet.green import urllib2
```

So you will get the url body with:

```
def fetch(url):
    body = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    return body
```

See more `eventlet` examples [here](http://eventlet.net/doc/examples.html).

Comment: Also, directly using the eventlet execution pools http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html should automatically monkey patch io calls.

Comment: But then wouldn't `processes_data(data)` still block and make the combined result slower than before?

Answer (score 0):

I would create two tasks, one for downloading the data and the other for processing it once it is downloaded. This way you could scale the two tasks independently. See: [Routing](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/next-steps.html#routing), [Chains](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#chains).

Comment: Doesn't look like a solution. Workers will still get stuck waiting for io to complete. The goal is to have 1 worker download multiple urls at once.